# Display high resolution image

Tags: c#, image, memorystream

I'm saving both high resolution and compressed version of high resolution image in the database.

When the user requests a high resolution image, i need to display that else the compressed one. here is my code.

The issue is : when i set that image byte array into a stream and bitmap, file size has compressed 2.27MB to 339kB.

What i'm doing wrong here?

```
private void DisplayImageFromBytes(byte[] byteArray, int resizeWidth, bool isHiResImage)   {

if (isHiResImage)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (resizeWidth > 0 && img.Width > resizeWidth)
    {
        int newHeight = (int)((float)img.Height * ((float)resizeWidth / (float)img.Width));
        bitmap = new Bitmap(img, resizeWidth, newHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(img);
    }
    Response.ContentType = "image/Jpeg";
    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    stream.Dispose();
    img.Dispose();
    bitmap.Dispose();
}
else
{
    DisplayImageFromBytes(byteArray, resizeWidth);
}
```

}

Comment: SO does your high resolution image format is Jpeg?

Comment: yes.. currently any image type can be uploaded!

Comment: You are using same image format for all the image came into you.   

Just try to use img.RawFormat insted of System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg. in bitmap.Save(); and see if it works for you.

Comment: and you don't need to create a new bitmap that dont need any conversion. you can directly save it to stream form  System.Drawing.Image img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same image format to save it to stream for all the different format of images that came into you.

For now just replace

```
bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

with

```
bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, img.RawFormat);
```

[RawFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat.aspx): will get the current file format of this Image.

N.B: You don't need to create a new bitmap that don't need any conversion. you can directly save it to stream from `System.Drawing.Image img`